# R scrape tables from multiple, unique urls

Tags: r, rvest

I'm looking to scrape tables from multiple, unique URLs that I have listed in a column of an excel sheet. I have the correct code ready to go for scraping from a single url:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)

onepage <- read_html("https://spd.gsd.state.nm.us/WebPortal/Modules/Procurement/Public/ProcurementsWebViewHistoricDetail.aspx?ID=geydyybpyy4yycey8rydyyboyysoycoygryn4yndybeyycoygwydnyy")

Procdetail <- onepage %>% html_element ("#ContentPlaceHolder1_divSoleSource.table.table-condensed.table-borderless") %>%
html_table ()
```

And the Excel with all the other URLs read into R

```
 data <- read_excel("test.xlsx")
    urls <- (data$URL)
```

The remaining URLs are not just permutations of one another, unfortunately. Instead, they all have random unique url endings. Here are two more URLs for example:

https://spd.gsd.state.nm.us/WebPortal/Modules/Procurement/Public/ProcurementsWebViewHistoricDetail.aspx?ID=grydyybpyy5yypoygwydyyboyysoycoygryn4ynfybgoyceygyydqyy
https://spd.gsd.state.nm.us/WebPortal/Modules/Procurement/Public/ProcurementsWebViewHistoricDetail.aspx?ID=grydyybpyy5oyqeygwydyyboyysoycoygryn4yboyyayycoygoydqyy

Any suggestions for how I can automate scraping these tables from all these unique URLs? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a function and then use lapply to run through the vector of urls.

```
read_my_urls <- function(url){

    onepage <- read_html(url)

     Procdetail <- onepage %>% html_element("#ContentPlaceHolder1_divSoleSource.table.table-condensed.table-borderless") %>%
html_table ()
 Procdetail
}

my_scraped_data <- lapply(data$urls, read_my_urls)
```

Comment: That did it! My hero! Recognize that's a pretty simple solution, but I'm new to R and was having a hard time figuring it out on my own. Thanks Elin!